# Dynamic clock in C++

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, clock

I would like to implement a dynamic clock in my C++ programm, that doesn't just show me the current time when the programm started but also keeps ticking when the programm is running. Is there an easy way of doing so? The programm shouldn't also be stuck in a loop while doing this, since the clock is only one of other functions.
What I've thought of, is using the observer pattern, but if there is a simpler way, I would appreciate it since I'm struggling with the pattern.

Comment: Any reason why `std::chrono` doesn't fit your use case. Could you give a pseudocode of what you expect to happen.

Comment: How about an OS timer which calls your clock a few times every second. Your clock could then check the time and if it changed since the last call you update the clock UI.

Comment: I did use std::chrono to display the time, but I want it to be dynamically. So, when I run my programm, I want to see the seconds ticking. Unfortunately, I can't use a loop that shows the time and clears the screen every second, because that would mean that my programm is stuck and can't execute other functions.

Comment: So basically you want to know how to do more than one thing at a time. where are you displaying the clock - in the console?

Comment: Well, kind of. It should more or less work in the background, so the programm doesn't get stuck in a loop. I am using Qt, so I would display it as String in a Widget there (works fine with the non-dynamic clock).

Comment: just setup a `QTimer` firing once a second?

Comment: Are you aware of the [Qt: Digital Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-digitalclock-example.html)? There is also an analog variant: [Qt: Analog Clock Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html). ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
 QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
 connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onEverySecond()));
 timer->start(1000);
}

void Foo::onEverySecond()
{
  //do fancy stuff
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Had to change the SIGNAL in connect statement a bit though:     connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onEverySecond()));

Answer (score 0):

If you use qt as mentioned before. It's better to use new signal-slot syntax as:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &ThisClassName::onEverySecond);
timer->start(1000);
```